# Are there any open source projects for car engine sound simulation?

Tags: sound, simulations

I have been thinking how to create realistic sound for a car. The main sound is the engine, then all kind of wind, road and suspension sounds.

Are there any open source projects for the engine sound simulation? Simply pitching up the sample does not sound too great. The ideal would be to something that allows me to pick type of the engine (i.e. inline-4 vs v-8), add extras like turbo/supercharger whine and finally set the load and rpm.

Edit: Something like http://www.sonory.org/examples.html

Comment: Feel free to add some of that information as an answer rather than an edit; you seem to have found some useful stuff so deserve some rep for it.

Comment: The Sonory technology sounds very nice.  I have never heard something like that.  It's really like the motor was alive.  Physical Modeling Synthesis is extremely complex to develop.  There are a lot of white papers on the subject.

Answer (score 22):

On one driving game I worked on, we had multiple samples per car - the engine held at certain rev intervals, and a sample each of the car ascending and descending the rev scale IIRC.

All of these were recorded from the exhaust, the sides, the front, and inside the real-life car so the sound could change as you moved the camera.  Then we blended between them depending on what the engine was doing right now.

It sounded awesome, but obviously it took a lot of resources!

Comment: That's called grain table synthesis, and yes, I've seen it in two completely different games companies and it leads to awesome quality motor sounds.

Comment: @RichardFabian Never heard of GTS. Thanks for putting it out here! +1

Answer (score 9):

See ["Capturing Engine Sounds for Games"](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2935/capturing_engine_sounds_for_games.php?print=1) for ideas about how the pros do it.  The article references [this SDK](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2965/product_review_analog_devices_.php), which I worked on. Unfortunately, it is no longer supported. It was free, so there may be copies floating around somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Small university project of [mine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaJlUyA8Kr0), calculates 4 given engine sound sample-sets to represent realistic engine sound.

Have fun!

Comment: Really cool stuff. Would you please attach some document or reference material with the video so its easier to get things under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Couple papers about this topic:

Design of a Driving Simulation Sound Engine
http://www.nads-sc.uiowa.edu/dscna07/DSCNA07CD/papers/Section%207B%20-%20Simulator%20Characteristics%20-%20Sight%20and%20Sound/Heitbrink.pdf

Sound Synthesis for Virtual Reality and Computer Games (ch 6-4) http://circle.ubc.ca/bitstream/handle/2429/10055/ubc_1999-389936.pdf?sequence=1

Answer (score 3):

There is a very interesting thread on the subject here:
http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/gameaudiopro/message/15158

They discuss Sonory, Physical Modeling, Granular Synthesis, Pitch shifting, etc.  Also, they briefly explain the tech in Need For Speed.

Answer (score 1):

---

Live for speed I think records the cylinder ignition sound for one stroke and then programmatically adds more cylinders depending on car engine (ex. v12) and produces sound that way...

Answer (score 0):

Here is it : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7c89_YSZZQ
Audiomotors by Audiogaming

Comment: Hello Fab, welcome to gamedev stackexchange! Please provide additional information to the link you posted. Like, what are the key features of it? Be creative! :)