# Sounds for Car racing game

Tags: sound, sound-effects, racing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Car engine sound simulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/car-engine-sound-simulation)

M working on 3d car racing game . Being assigned the task of creating sound effects for the car. I have all the sounds with me like idle engine sound , onLow sound, onMid sound and onHigh sound ......now the issue is i dont know how actually the other games use these sounds to create awesome sound effects .. 
 Does anyone have any idea how to implement my sounds for car when it runs and changes gear all that ?

EDIT:-

- When the car is at start line there would be idle engine sound.
- on 1st gear the sound of accelerating car till 2nd gear.
- before second gear the car sound drops (actual rpm of car drops) then gear shift and again boost in the sound and so on..

I need to simulate these events in the game. I am given with three sounds :-

1. sound for low speed
2. sound for mid speed
3. sound for high speed

these are steady sounds of engines at a particular rpm levels of a engine...
Hope now things are clear

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty vague question; you might get lucky and someone has a link to a tutorial about audio for a car racing game, but otherwise you should probably tell us specifics about what you've tried and why that didn't work so that we can suggest ways to improve it.