# How to achieve realistic engine sound?

Tags: audio, car

I am aiming to achieve a believable engine sound for a car. The vehicles are simplified versions of their real-world counterparts, with simpler steering behaviors and acceleration, etc.

This seems like a fairly complicated topic to me, which I must not take lightly. So, how would I find/capture sounds of a car's engine, properly segmented in a way they can be used inside a game?

Also, what kind of format do I need the sound files in? How do I separate the sounds in multiple files so they can be used by such an algorithm?

I'm not sure this is even the way to go about it, but my wild guess would be to create an algorithm that would take as input the car's shift, current velocity and other engine parameters and output the correct sound at the correct time. How would you do such a thing?

Comment: Start here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/are-there-any-open-source-projects-for-car-engine-sound-simulation then here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230487/engine-sounds-in-racing-computer-games

Comment: I'd highly recommend you poke around back issues of Game Developer Magazine (http://gdmag.com) and also the GDC Vault -- for example, http://gdcvault.com/play/1015351/Racing-Games-A-Semi-Formal .  There are quite a few presentations and bits of literature floating around about this!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could record the sound instead of buying a stock sound from a website. You could possibly spend less money that way.

Comment: I am more interested in actual algorithms than the sounds themselves, that would be a bonus. What I really need is some insight on how to play different sounds for different speeds/shifts/etc..